# How to get the data from model relationship for query builder?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a Product model where a 'belongsTo' relationship has been set with my Plan model. I can usually retrieve the plan name of a certain product in the blade file by doing `{{$product->plan->name}}`.

Now I'm currently trying to build a search feature where the user can search for a product name or a plan name that is related to a product.

In my controller, the idea is to get the results from the search by querying the Product model, and looking for the product name that is like the one that was input by the user. I'm trying to find a way to look for the plan name that is like the one input by the user as well but I cannot seem to get it right.

This is the query I'm currently doing:

```
$results = Product::where('name', 'like', '%', $request->input('search-product-name'), '%')
        ->join('plans', 'products.plan_id', '=', 'plans.id')
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%', $request->input('search-product-plan'), '%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `whereHas` for filter data from `relationship` table assume  you have set `plan` as `relationship` function inside `Product` model so you code will be like this

```php
$results = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'. $request->input('search-product-name'). '%')
    ->whereHas("plan", function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%'. $request->input('search-product-plan'). '%');
    })->get();
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: I tried this and this error shows up `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'exists (select * from `plans` where `products`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`id` stand...' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `products` where `name` like % exists (select * from `plans` where `products`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`id` standard `name` like %))`

Comment: fixed it try now

Comment: it went thru but when I dd() it, it returns 3 items instead of just 1. i only filled 1 of the input fields which is the plan name and it's supposed to return products with that plan name only. this is the result of dd(): `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1015 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Product {#1054 ▶}
    1 => App\Product {#1053 ▶}
    2 => App\Product {#1262 ▶}
  ]
}`

Comment: nevermind, i just used whereHas instead of orWhereHas, thank you very much Kamlesh!